# Is it possible to run wget using both -O and -P options together?

Tags: terminal, wget

I want to download a program.  For example "package.zip"

I want to download it in, for example "~/programs/downloaded"

I want to name it, for example "new.zip"

So I tried:

```
wget -P ~/programs/downloaded \
     -O new.zip   https://somewebsite.com/package.zip
```

But it only downloaded the package in the terminal's current directory and renamed it. The `-P` command does not work.  Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

This is a *feature* of `wget` that has bitten many people. Unfortunately, it was a design decision taken many years ago and cannot be changed now for fear of breaking existing scripts. The crucial thing to understand here is that `-O` acts like shell redirection and hence is unaffected by the `-P` option.

The way to do what you want would be to directly provide the filename:

```
wget -O ~/programs/downloaded/new.zip <url>
```